# how to display data dynamically in jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

I have created a function that processes some value.
Now, my problem is that the graph i create displays the values generated after ALL the values have been calculated. i want to generate the graph such that the as and when the data is calculated; it must be plotted on the data.
The calculation and the display of data in the graph must appear parallel.
I have generated the graph as:

```
 dataset.addSeries(series1); 
 dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

 series1 = new XYSeries("% ERROR");
 chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Percent Error", "Number of Records", "% Error", dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true, true, true);
 chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
 frame = new ChartFrame("Error graph", chart);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

The series1 is plotted on the graph.the values in series1 is added on every iteration of the loop which generates some value.
Can it be done using wait and notify? I am not really sure about this functions. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The [`add()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#add%28double,%20double%29) method of `XYSeries` "Adds a data item to the series and sends a `SeriesChangeEvent` to all registered listeners." One approach is to invoke [`add()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#add%28double,%20double%29) using `javax.swing.Timer`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852).

Answer (score 0):

If your data are computed within a fix period what about using DinamycTimeSeriesCollection?
They are very usefull.

You can find an example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856979/jfreechart-dynamictimeseries-with-period-of-n-milliseconds/6864036#6864036) where I managed the problem of having periods multiple of a millisecond.