# Set no. of MilliSecond for plot in JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am using MilliDTSC class in my program. I want the refresh rate to be set as 100ms . I have used javax.swing.Timer to update the GUI after 100ms, but my domain axis updates after each millisecond, because unit is 'MilliSecond' (as shown below)
[image: ScreenShot]

Is there any way to change the unit of domain axis to 100ms instead of 1ms ?

Comment: Try `axis.setDateFormatOverride()`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22264230/230513).

Comment: I could not get it, can you explain in  a better way as per my code 
It is posted here 

http://pastebin.com/2FbtDWme

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setRange(0, 1000);
domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(100));
```

and please put false in autorange like this :

```
domain.setAutoRange(false);
```

Edited:

Please Replace:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
final ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();

domain.setAutoRange(true);


NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis();
axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(100));

ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setRange(0, 100);
```

with :

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
final NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis)plot.getDomainAxis();

domain.setAutoRange(false);

domain.setRange(0,1000);
domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(100));

NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis(); 
range.setRange(0,100);
```

Comment: timeAxis is the reference of which Class ?
Please explain a bit more, I dont know much about this library

Comment: What your Time(ms) axis object is that is represented by me here as timeAxis

Comment: I have posted code here, 
http://pastebin.com/2FbtDWme

Now tell me whre should I do it

Comment: setTickUnit is not defined for 'domain' type (eclipse shows an error)

Comment: and why are you editing the range axis, I need to edit only domain axis

Comment: thanks brother for sparing your valuable time and helping me, but eclipse is giving a class cast exception when we try to cast to NumberAxis

"  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jfree.c
hart.axis.DateAxis cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis "

Comment: so please try to replace NumberAxis to DateAxis for domain only and best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

No need to use any methods, they will give one or another exception, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6864036/230513) answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856979/jfreechart-dynamictimeseries-with-period-of-n-milliseconds?rq=1). You will have to create one class, `MultipleOfMillisecond`. After that, you can customize the time period according to your choice, as per argument passed to constructor of `MultipleOfMillisecond`.